# Pairing with bluetooth device without using inbuilt dialog with pin

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to pair with the bluetooth device without showing pairing dialog, through my app UI pin should be set to the intented device. I am not sure either it is possible or not.

Pairing device code is below:

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
            method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




private final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {             
                 final int state        = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
                 final int prevState    = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                 if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                     showToast("Paired");

                     finish();
                 } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                     showToast("Unpaired");
                 }


            }
        }
    };
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I dont think so, its possible, because of security concern.

Comment: yeah but there must be some alternative for that..

Comment: may be and may not be also, dont know, but good question, let me research on it.

Comment: yup, sure, but what's the need of this functionality can you please tell me?

Comment: its increasing one more step in app. so just to minimize the extra step for user..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57988/discussion-between-pratik-and-girl).